# 404 error when browsing to endpoint of a self hosted WCF service

Tags: wcf

I'm having an issue when i connect to an endpoint using WCF Test Client i get the message

Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:8080/evals/basic

I'm adding the endpoints and starting the host in code using

```
    private ServiceHost _serviceHost;

    public ServiceHost ServiceHost
    {
        get { return _serviceHost?? (_serviceHost= new ServiceHost(typeof(EvalService))); }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IEvalService),
                                new BasicHttpBinding(),
                                "http://localhost:8080/evals/basic");
        ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IEvalService),
                                new WSHttpBinding(),
                                "http://localhost:8080/evals/ws");
        ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IEvalService),
                                new NetTcpBinding(),
                                "net.tcp://localhost:1002/evals");
        ServiceHost.Open();
    }
```

and when i check the status using this method

```
    private void ShowServiceInfo()
    {
        var message = String.Format("{0} is {1} with these endpoints:\n", _host.ServiceHost.Description.ServiceType, _host.ServiceHost.State);
        foreach (var serviceEndpoint in _host.ServiceHost.Description.Endpoints)
        {
            message += "\n" + serviceEndpoint.Address;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
```

then i get this message which looks like everything is running ok

HostService.EvalService is Opened with these endpoints:

http://localhost:8080/evals/basic
http://localhost:8080/evals/ws
net.tcp://localhost:1002/evals

Anyone have any idea why browsing to the endpoint will not work?

Comment: Permissions?  Tried running your app as admin?  I've noticed apps can't communicate w/ each other unless endpoints are allowed (forget how) or you run the app as admin.  Maybe the same in a single app.

Comment: Would that just be when UAC is enabled because i don't have UAC turned on. Also when i try to configure the endpoints via App.config i get this exception
---------------------------
System.InvalidOperationException: Service 'HostService.EvalService' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.

Comment: also if i set the startup project to my WCF Project then i get this exception in the WCF Service Host

System.InvalidOperationException: The HttpGetEnabled property of ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true and the HttpGetUrl property is a relative address, but there is no http base address.  Either supply an http base address or set HttpGetUrl to an absolute address.

Comment: ok so the issue with setting the startup project to my WCF project was that i didn't have a host set up for the service. But when i self host it in anther app like listed above it gives me the same 404 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues - but can't verify those (you didn't provide the necessary config file):

1) You don't seem to have any MEX endpoints - an endpoint to exchange metadata about the service on. Those need to be added explicitly to your service host - you can have MEX endpoints for HTTP or Net.Tcp protocols

2) I cannot verify whether or not you've enabled service metadata as a service behavior on your service - typically this is done from config (which you didn't provide), or you can add this behavior in code, too - but it must be added explicitly.

```
ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior;
metadataBehavior = ServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

if(metadataBehavior == null)
{
   metadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
   metadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
   ServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);
}
```

Without any MEX infrastructure in place, no client can query your service for its methods and parameters - that's why the WCF Test Client won't work. Add the service metadata behavior, and at least one MEX endpoint, and you should be fine.

Comment: Ok i think that got be on the right track, So there needs to be a mex endpoint for every service?

Comment: @Nitro52 : If you want "discoverability" - yes, that requires MEX, and thus both the MEX service behavior and a MEX endpoint. The service as such will work just fine without MEX - but you just cannot "discover" and ask it for its methods and such.

Comment: I have the mex endpoint added and still it dont work.. check my post  with all relevant code here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192877/selfhosted-wcf-service-cant-be-tested-via-wcftestclient

Comment: @user20358: added a response to your question