# Selfhosted WCF service cant be tested via WCFTestClient

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I am trying to test my self hosted wcf service using WCFTestClient. I get an error like so:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:2303/MyService If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://localhost:2303/MyService    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:2303/MyService'.    Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:2303/MyService.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.    The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..HTTP GET Error    URI: http://localhost:2303/MyService    There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:2303/MyService'.    The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.

My project structure is as follows

1. Console Application that acts as host
2. Service Contract
3. Service implementation

Here are my service implementation and Contract classes, which are in two separate projects.

```
namespace MyService
{
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        public string GetGreeting(string name)
        {
            return "Hello " + name;
        }

        public string GetYelling(string name)
        {
            return "What the hell " + name + "!!";
        }
    }
}

namespace MyService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetGreeting(string name);

        [OperationContract]
        string GetYelling(string name);
    }
}
```

This is the console app

```
namespace MyWCFHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService.MyService), new Uri("http://localhost:2303"));
            serviceHost.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("MyService is running...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            serviceHost.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the config file

```
<configuration>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name ="MyService.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyService.MyServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:2303/MyService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyService.IMyService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mexpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>

    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyService.MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>


</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time...

**Edit**

The service works when I try to run it via a winforms client so I know the service is working. Question is how do I get it ready for testing as well, using WcfTestClient.

Comment: offtopic but you have the name of the class same as your namespace, perfect element for confusions down the line

Comment: I agree, but this is a study project, so I let it be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you have a problem with your MEX endpoint. You're currently only specifying a relative address ("mex") - but there's no base address for HTTP defined in your service ......

I would suggest to:

- either define a base address and then use only relative addresses "on top" of that - for your regular and your MEX endpoint

OR:

- define your addresses as full, complete addresses - not just for your regular endpoints, but in that case for the MEX endpoint as well.

So change your config to be something like:

```
<service name ="MyService.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyService.MyServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint 
        address="http://localhost:2303/MyService" 
        binding="basicHttpBinding" 
        contract="MyService.IMyService"/>
    <endpoint name="mexpoint" 
        address="http://localhost:2303/MyService/mex" 
        binding="mexHttpBinding" 
        contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

and then I hope you should be able to get at your metadata and thus connect to your service!

Comment: awesome!! that worked. Thanks Marc. However, now that it is working in WcfTestClient, I tried checking if I could see something when I hit the URL http://localhost:2303/MyService in a browser window. I get an HTTP 400 bad request. Any pointers here?

Comment: Also, for a cassini hosted service we dont need to specify a base address. That config was what I pulled out from a working cassini hosted wcf service. Is there something Cassini is adding then under the covers?

Comment: @user20358: it's a **SOAP** service - you cannot "hit" a SOAP service from a browser - your browser doesn't talk SOAP. You should be able to get the WSDL though (you've enabled `HttpGetEnabled` on your serviceMetadata) by going to `http://localhost:2303/MyService/mex?WSDL`

Comment: thanks.. I am trying to understand what the svc file does, that allows the service to be accessed via a browser. Not that it is getting executed, but it does provide the wsdl in the browser when you enter the service url ending in .svc

Comment: @usr20358: the *.svc file is the helper file that IIS needs in order to understand what to do when a request for that URL comes in. That's how IIS knows what service host to instantiate, what service class to pass to the host, and so forth. In a self-hosted environment, you don't need *.svc files.

Comment: http://localhost:2303/MyService/mex?WSDL didnt work and gave me the same HTTP 400 bad request.

Comment: I tried that already.. same thing..  I also tried http://myMachineName:2303/MyService?WSDL and http://myMachineName:2303/MyService/mex?WSDL  .. all gave same bad request.

Comment: I believe I am following the same pluralsight tutorials as user20358, and in the tutorial he opens up Firefox and hits the web service and gets an XML response which is a SOAP envelope. I however also get a 400 error.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Windows 7?

Try running:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:2303/MyService user=DOMAIN\user
```

More [info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx) and here [too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd767317.aspx)

Comment: yes, I am using Win 7. Also, what do I put for DOMAIN\user.. I am running this on my home pc that is not connected to any domain. Does the user need to be the logged in user?.. I suppose it does.. does it?

Comment: The service works when I try to run it via a winforms client so I know the service is working. Question is how do I get it ready for testing as well, using WcfTestClient.

Comment: the command netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:2303/MyService user=PCNAME\mylogin  gave me this: Url reservation add failed, Error: 87

Comment: Hmm interesting, it works from winforms. What does this command give u: netsh http show urlacl

Comment: It shows a list of URL Reservations. What am I to look for in this?.. I doesnt show my URL in the list. I also dont understand what those terms 'User, Listen, Delegate, SDDL' that come under each URL mean..

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your visual studio as administrator. Then you do not need to manually run the commands like (url=http://+:2303/MyService user=PCNAME\mylogin )